# Prove that for any $N \geq 0$ the set $A_N = $ {{$x_n$} $\in A: x_n=0$ for $n \geq N$} is compact.

Tags: real-analysis

Define the set $A \subseteq {\ell}^2$ by

$A  = ${{$x_n$} $\in {\ell}^2 : \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+n){|x_n|}^2 \leq 1$}

i) Prove that for any $N \geq 0$ the set $A_N = $ {{$x_n$} $\in A: x_n=0$ for $n \geq N$} is compact?

So we must show there exists a subsequence {$x_{n_k}$} that converges to a point in $A$.

Well, if {$x_n$} is a sequence in $A_N$ and since {$x_n$} = $0$ then woudn't it be trivial that its subsequence {$x_{n_k}$} also converges to $0$ and hence $A_N$ is compact.

ii) Prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some $N \geq 0$ so that for any $x \in A$ we have

$d_2(x,A_N)< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

How would I approach this part?

Comment: Careful. Elements of $A$ are themselves sequences, so a sequence of elements in $A$ is a *sequence of sequences*.

Comment: Why do you say that $\{x_n\}=0$?

Comment: The subspace $\{\{x_n\} \in \ell^2 : n \ge N \implies x_n = 0\}$ is finite-dimensional, and $A_n$ is a closed and bounded subset of this subspace, hence it is compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part is answered in the comments. For the second part take $N$ such that $\frac 1 {N+1} <(\epsilon/2)^{2}$. Given $x \in A$ consider $y$ defined by $y_i=x_i$ for $i <N$ and $y_i=0$ for $i \geq N$. Then $y \in A_N$ and $\|x-y\|^{2}=\sum_{n\geq N} |x_n|^{2} \leq \frac 1 {N+1} \sum_{n\geq N} (1+n) |x_n|^{2}\leq \frac 1 {N+1}$ because $x \in A$. Hence $\|x-y\|<\epsilon /2$and so $d(x,A_N) <\epsilon /2$

Comment: Why does $|x-y|^2 = \sum |x_n|^2$?

Comment: See my  definition of $y$ and apply definition of norm in $\ell^{2}$.